# Scala: Generalised method to find match and return match dependant values in collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I wish to find a match within a List and return values dependant on the match. The CollectFirst works well for matching on the elements of the collection but in this case I want to match on the member swEl of the element rather than on the element itself.

```
abstract class CanvNode (var swElI: Either[CSplit, VistaT])
{         
  private[this] var _swEl: Either[CSplit, VistaT] = swElI
  def member = _swEl
  def member_= (value: Either[CSplit, VistaT] ){ _swEl = value; attach}
  def attach: Unit
  attach

  def findVista(origV: VistaIn): Option[Tuple2[CanvNode,VistaT]] = member match
  {
    case Right(v) if (v == origV) => Option(this, v) 
    case _ => None
  }
}

def nodes(): List[CanvNode] = topNode :: splits.map(i => List(i.n1, i.n2)).flatten

//Is there a better way of implementing this? 
val temp: Option[Tuple2[CanvNode, VistaT]] = 
  nodes.map(i => i.findVista(origV)).collectFirst{case Some (r) => r}
```

**Do I need a View on that, or will the collectFirst method ensure the collection is only created as needed?**

It strikes me that this must be a fairly general pattern. Another example could be if one had a List member of the main List's elements and wanted to return the fourth element if it had one. **Is there a standard method I can call?** Failing that I can create the following:

```
implicit class TraversableOnceRichClass[A](n: TraversableOnce[A])
{
  def findSome[T](f: (A) => Option[T]) = n.map(f(_)).collectFirst{case Some (r) => r}
}
```

And then I can replace the above with:

```
val temp: Option[Tuple2[CanvNode, VistaT]] = 
  nodes.findSome(i => i.findVista(origV))
```

This uses implicit classes from 2.10, for pre 2.10 use:

```
class TraversableOnceRichClass[A](n: TraversableOnce[A])
{
  def findSome[T](f: (A) => Option[T]) = n.map(f(_)).collectFirst{case Some (r) => r}
}

implicit final def TraversableOnceRichClass[A](n: List[A]):
  TraversableOnceRichClass[A] = new TraversableOnceRichClass(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an introductory side node: The operation you're describing (return the first `Some` if one exists, and `None` otherwise) is the sum of a collection of `Option`s under the "first" monoid instance for `Option`. So for example, with [Scalaz 6](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/wiki/Scalaz6):

```
scala> Stream(None, None, Some("a"), None, Some("b")).map(_.fst).asMA.sum
res0: scalaz.FirstOption[java.lang.String] = Some(a)
```

Alternatively you could put something like this in scope:

```
implicit def optionFirstMonoid[A] = new Monoid[Option[A]] {
  val zero = None
  def append(a: Option[A], b: => Option[A]) = a orElse b
}
```

And skip the `.map(_.fst)` part. Unfortunately neither of these approaches is appropriately lazy in Scalaz, so the entire stream will be evaluated (unlike Haskell, where `mconcat . map (First . Just) $ [1..]` is just fine, for example).

---

Edit: As a side note to this side note: apparently Scalaz *does* provide a `sumr` that's appropriately lazy (for streams—none of these approaches will work on a view). So for example you can write this:

```
Stream.from(1).map(Some(_).fst).sumr
```

And not wait forever for your answer, just like in the Haskell version.

---

But assuming that we're sticking with the standard library, instead of this:

```
n.map(f(_)).collectFirst{ case Some(r) => r }
```

I'd write the following, which is more or less equivalent, and arguably more idiomatic:

```
n.flatMap(f(_)).headOption
```

For example, suppose we have a list of integers.

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

We can make this lazy and `map` a function with a side effect over it to show us when its elements are accessed:

```
val ys = xs.view.map { i => println(i); i }
```

Now we can `flatMap` an `Option`-returning function over the resulting collection and use `headOption` to (safely) return the first element, if it exists:

```
scala> ys.flatMap(i => if (i > 2) Some(i.toString) else None).headOption
1
2
3
res0: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(3)
```

So clearly this stops when we hit a non-empty value, as desired. And yes, you'll definitely need a view if your original collection is strict, since otherwise `headOption` (or `collectFirst`) can't reach back and stop the `flatMap` (or `map`) that precedes it.

In your case you can skip `findVista` and get even more concise with something like this:

```
val temp = nodes.view.flatMap(
  node => node.right.toOption.filter(_ == origV).map(node -> _)
).headOption
```

Whether you find this clearer or just a mess is a matter of taste, of course.

Comment: headOption is from TraversableLike. Pimping TraversableLike is a bit more tricky than pimping TraversableOnce so I will have to get to grips with that before checking your answer.